# Control a robot remotely with joystick using ROS

Tags: ros, wheeled-robot, python, ros-noetic

Could anybody help me out controlling my robot remotely with a joystick. I will try to give all the information needed here below and explain what goes wrong.

I use a Jetson Nano which had ROS running on it. I have 2 Arduino's connected to is one is used for sensors and the other I use specifically for controlling the motors. In the source code on the Arduino Motor Controller I subscribed to a joy node. When I connect my joystick (Logiteck Extreme 3d Pro) to a usb port of the Jetson Nano I can control the bot perfectly.
But I would like to control the bot remotely over WiFi so I had to add some code to the .bashrc file which I did, I added Ip address and I am able to connect over WiFi to the bot. I know this because with a rostopic echo I can read sensor values. And when I start RVIZ I can even see that vizualized.
So I think connection has been made over WiFi. And like I said when I connect the joystick directly to the Jetson I can control the bot. But when I connect the oystick to my desktop (using VMware Linux Ubuntu 20.04) I can't control the robot. When plugged in and write in the terminal on the Jetson `ls /dev/input` the jetson doesn't see any joystick.
But running on my desktop `rosrun joy joy_node` I clearly see that the joystick is working. In order to give as much of good information here all the code I use:

Launch File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<launch>
  <!-- Start the rosserial Python node -->
  <node name="rosserial_python" pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py">
    <!-- Replace "/dev/ttyUSB0" with your Arduino's serial port -->
    <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyUSB0" />
    <param name="baud" value="57600" />  <!-- Set the appropriate baud rate for your Arduino -->
  </node>

  <!-- Start the Control Input node-->
  <node name="control_input" pkg="r2g2" type="control_input.py" />
  <!-- Start State Control node-->
  <node name="joystick_counter" pkg="r2g2" type="state_control.py" />

  <!-- Start the joy node so the joystick works automatically after starting up-->
  <node name="joy_node" pkg="joy" type="joy_node" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find r2g2)/config/joy_config.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>

  <!-- Start RVIZ -->
  <!--Robot Description from URDF-->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find r2g2)/urdf/r2g2.xacro"/>

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/>

  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher"/>

  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find r2g2)/r2g2.rviz" />

</launch>
```

Joystick config file:

```
# joy_config.yaml

# Configuration for Logitech Extreme 3D joystick
joy_node:
  deadzone: 0.1
  autorepeat_rate: 20
  coalesce_interval: 0.001
  dev: /dev/input/js0  # Replace X with the appropriate number (usually 0 for the first joystick)
  axes:
    - x: 0
      y: 1
      deadzone: 0.1
    - x: 3
      y: 4
      deadzone: 0.1
    - x: 2  # Twist (rudder) axis
      deadzone: 0.1
  buttons:
    - 1  # Trigger button
    - 2  # Thumb button
    - 3  # Top left button
    - 4  # Top right button
    - 5  # Top middle button
    - 6  # Left base button
    - 7  # Right base button
    - 8  # Bottom left button
    - 9  # Bottom right button
    - 10  # Base button 1
    - 11  # Base button 2
    - 12  # Base button 3
    - 13  # Base button 4
```

Joystick subscriber running on the Jetson Nano

```
import rospy
import math
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy
from r2g2.msg import Control_State

# Global variables used for processing the input value from the joystick
Xvelocity = 0
Yvelocity = 0
Zvelocity = 0
Max_Velocity = 100                              # Max velocity in rpm

# Global variables which will be published for left and right motor speed
Left_Motor_Speed = 0
Right_Motor_Speed = 0
Rotation_Speed = 0

# Initialize control input node
rospy.init_node("control_input", anonymous=True)

# Callback funtion for the Control State of R2G2 depending on the value a different 
control will be accomplished
def control_state_callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo("Current control state is: %d", data.control_state_value)
    print(data.control_state_value)

def joystick_callback(data):
 # Get joystick values max scale from joystick is -1 to 1 for x, y and z axis
    axes = data.axes
    global Yvelocity                             # Y position joystick represents Forward and Backwards velocity
    global Xvelocity                             # X position joystick represents turn angle will be used for difference in motor speed
    #global Zvelocity                             # Z position joystick represents rotation around Bot axis
    #Zvelocity = axes[2] * Max_Velocity           # Scale joystick value to rpm value   
    Yvelocity = axes[1] * Max_Velocity           # Scale joystick value to rpm value
    Xvelocity = axes[0] * Max_Velocity           # Scale joystick value to rpm value   
    process_velocities(Xvelocity, Yvelocity)

def process_velocities(x_val, y_val):
# First check if x and y values are not equal to zero
    if x_val == 0:
        # If the X position of the joystick is 0 than the bot drives straight and not further computation has to be done
        # Therefore both motors run equal speed.
        Left_Motor_Speed = y_val
        Right_Motor_Speed = y_val
    else:
        hyp = math.sqrt(x_val**2 + y_val**2)                # Find the hypothenuse of the two vectors
        vel_factor = abs(y_val/hyp)                         # Compute the cosine and use it as a attenuation factor for one of the wheels
        if x_val > 0:                                       # If x pos joystick is > 0, R2G2 needs to move to left, left motor turns slower as right motor
            Left_Motor_Speed = vel_factor * y_val
            Right_Motor_Speed = y_val
        else:                                               # If x pos joystick is < 0, R2G2 needs to move to right, right motor turns slower as left motor
            Left_Motor_Speed = y_val
            Right_Motor_Speed = vel_factor * y_val    

    # Publish the computed velocities for each motor
    left_vel_pub.publish(Left_Motor_Speed)
    right_vel_pub.publish(Right_Motor_Speed)

 # Create subscriber to Joystick node 
 def joystick_subscriber():
    rospy.Subscriber('joy', Joy, joystick_callback)
    rospy.spin()

 # Create Velocity publishers
left_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher("/left_velocity", Float32, queue_size=5)
right_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher("/right_velocity", Float32, queue_size=5)
# rotation_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher("/rotation_velocity", Float32, queue_size=10 )

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    rospy.Subscriber("/control_state", Control_State, control_state_callback)
    joystick_subscriber()
```

Lastley the .bashrc file:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

 if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
     color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\ 
   [\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\\\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\\\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
 alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi

fi
```

#Uncomment this line to create a connection to ROS-core on the Jetson-Nano
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.XXX.XXX:11311
export ROS_IP=192.168.XXX.XXX

source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

I have of course also code runing on the Arduino but I don't think there is the issue cause when I connect the joystick to the Jetson directly it all works fine. The issue must lie somewhere between the desktop and Jetson Nano. I truly hope I have given enough information so someone could point out to me what I do wrong.

Comment: "when I connect the joystick directly to the Jetson I can control the bot.... When plugged in and write in the terminal on the Jetson ls /dev/input the jetson doesn't see any joystick. But running on my desktop rosrun joy joy_node I clearly see that the joystick is working."  - so the joystick works on the jetson, but the jetson doesn't recognize the joystick- how is that possible?  And then the joystick is recognized on the desktop, but commands aren't communicated to the jetson over the wifi- if that's the whole problem make sure you can rostopic echo in both direction.

Comment: I have tested this further and further. The issue has been solved and had to do with a truned on firewall on my desktop and the network option on the VM needed to be bridged inorder to get corret IP addresses. Sad thing with free version of VMware I can do this only with LAN and not with WiFi so I use now a LAN cable on my desktop and all solved.